# Variável dentro do WHERE de um select

Tags: php, select, variáveis

Tenho uma variável que muda seu conteúdo de acordo com algumas ações do usuário!

Pretendo usar essa mesma variável dentro de um select, da seguinte forma!

```
" Select * FROM tabele WHERE '$variável' "
```

Porém quando aplico a `variável` no `Select` apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean
```

Como dito acima o conteúdo dessa variável é dinâmico, seu conteúdo pode ser:

```
$variavel = "Item1 = 'Dado'";
```

ou:

```
$variavel ="Item1 = 'Dado' AND Item2 = 'Dado'";
```

Varia de acordo com a ação do usuário. Porém, se eu adicionar o conteúdo da variável no `WHERE` diretamente, ele funciona perfeitamente. Ex:

```
" Select * FROM tabele WHERE Item1 = 'Dado' AND Item2 = 'Dado'"
```

> Minha dúvida é:
>
> > Como faço pra aplicar o conteúdo da variável dentro do select sem que apresente erro? Aparentemente tem haver com as aspas simples e duplas, mas já fiz algumas mudanças aqui e nada deu certo!

Comment: @Bacco o código é basicamente esse! A unica coisa que não acrescentei foi a função que forma o conteúdo da variável! Mas creio que co problema não seja com ela! Porque no meus testes desativei a função e o problema persistiu! Então to trabalhando apenas com a variável (que esta na pergunta) e o select (que também está na pergunta).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente é erro de sintaxe, isso não faz sentido:

```
"Select * FROM tabele WHERE '$variável'"
```

Pois quando faz

```
$variavel ="Item1 = 'Dado' AND Item2 = 'Dado'";
```

Sua query fica entre aspas

```
Select * FROM tabele WHERE 'Item1 = 'Dado' AND Item2 = 'Dado''
```

Esse tipo de erro pode ser facilmente detectado com um `echo $sql;` antes do envio da *query*. Para o seu caso, a linha seria esta:

```
"Select * FROM tabele WHERE $variável"
```

ou mais elegante, para evitar a interpolação na string toda:

```
'Select * FROM tabele WHERE '.$variável
```

Comment: O erro de fato foi meu! Era realmente erro de sintaxe e eu não vi! Um WHERE estava ficando vazio! Ficava algo tipo "WHERE item = Item2 = dado